how to understand value in `torch.Size`
I am studying NLP. output.last_hidden_state.size() shows torch.Size([1,6,768])
output.last_hidden_state[:,0].size() shows torch.Size([1,768])
I think [1,6,768] means there are 768 * [1,6] vectors.
If this could be true, then output.last_hidden_state[1,:] should be the second [1,6] vector, and output.last_hidden_state[1,:].size() should be torch.Size([1,6])
But no... it throws error: index 1 is out of bounds for dimension 0 with size 1.
